# How to perform CDC for mysql percona cluster and create topics for all dbs

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, debezium, maxwell

I was looking for a solution to capture all database changes(create,delete,update) from a 3 node percona mysql cluster and send the updates to visualization tool such as Kibana to search events. Many suggested mysql bin log--> Debezium/maxwell-->Apache kafka--> Ekasticsearch(kibana).
I have following questions on this setup,

1. Have i picked up the right solution
2. With 100s of databases and each db with 100 tables, how can I capture changes for all ? I see the topic could be created only for specific table and specific Database with debezium.
3. With maxwell, i could get all changes output , however unable to resume from where we left in the event of stopping and starting maxwell/ db.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: This will work fine. What specific issues are you experiencing?

Comment: How to get the consumer for all tables and all databases? Apache topic at the moment is for table.database.

Comment: By default, if you do not have `database.include.list`, all databases will be read by Debezium into individual topics, which is recommended because tables often have different schemas and putting different schemas in the same topic will cause confusion for consumers. On consumers, you can subscribe to lists of topics or regex patterns rather than single topic names

Comment: To use kibana as consumer do i have to write a consumer or there are prebuilt ones ?

Comment: Kibana is only a UI, not a Kafka consumer, so I dont understand the question. You can use Logstash [or Kafka Connect for writing data to Elasticsearch](https://www.confluent.io/blog/the-simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-in-the-world-or-thereabouts-part-2/) rather than writing your own consumer